# Can a RAID array be moved from a HP P410i to a Dell Perc S100?

Tags: raid, hp, dell, hp-smart-array, dell-perc

I have a HP Proliant ML350 G6 server with a HP P410i controller that failed miserably after a power spike. Can I move the RAID10 array to a Dell PowerEdge T310 with a Perc S100 controller without losing data?

Comment: How do you know the controller is damaged? Is there an error message you could share?

Comment: @ewwhite I read that as the server failed miserably otherwise why wouldnt he just replace the controller?

Comment: @JamesRyan You're right. Punctuation. Could be interpreted as a controller-only failure or "*I have a server that just happens to have this controller... and the entire thing failed*". The controller is motherboard-based, though... so replacement means a new system board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't move an HP Smart Array RAID group to a Dell Perc controller without reformatting. The array metadata is stored on the disks, so you'd need a system with an HP Smart Array controller to transfer the array set to.

The P410i controller is an embedded controller, so your ML350 G6 would need a new system board to repair. You could also substitute a [Smart Array P410 PCIe controller](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04111713) to use if your PCIe slots are still healthy. They're cheap and abundant.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Some other posts around here seem to suggest that major manufacturers support a common RAID metadata format. So deleting any previous array on the new controller and just inserting the old driver into the new controller should make it detect the array and logical drives and configure itself automatically.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. There is no commonality between HP Smart Array and PERC (LSI-based) RAID controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much then! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole A lot of OEMs use rebranded LSI cards so it would be where that is the case. The P400 is one of those, I don't think the P410 is.  Although you should probably be able to use an HP P410 card in a Dell server to get the data off if that is the hardware available.

Comment: @JamesRyan The P400 uses an LSI chipset, but HP Smart Array metadata. It's not compatible with LSI controllers. The P410 is a [PMC SIERA](http://pmcs.com) chipset, also with HP's RAID format. I'd just get a standalone P410 card. But I'm also curious, how do you know the controller is damaged?

Comment: The server might be good but I can't know for sure until tomorrow when I'm expecting a new PSU.